# Self-extracting EXE where command-line parameters are not compressed

Tags: setup-deployment, self-extracting, winzip

I'm currently using WinZip to create self-extracting EXEs.  In the past I have had to modify file names in the self-extracting EXE using a hex-editor, and this was easy because WinZip stores the file names as plain text, not compressed or encoded at all.  **I'm wondering if anyone is familiar enough with the formats of other programs like WinZip to know if any store the command-line parameters of the program to run after self-extraction is complete in an uncompressed format that is easy to modify with hex-editor?**  From check WinZip, it appears the parameters are stored in a weird format, because I see them several times in the resulting EXE and they don't appear to be easy to modify.

I'm not really modifying these in hex editor, I really just use that as an example that is easier to understand.  I actually modify this in ASP.NET code on my web server, as I stream the file for download, and inject some data that is specific to each download/session, that my app uses later after install.  I know I could build the EXE on my web server for each download, but I'd rather avoid the overhead on my server if I can... as it is, I already have to read in the file, modify it, write it back out, sign it, then let them download.  So compressing wouldn't be too much extra I suppose, but I'd rather avoid if as easy as just using a different app to build my self-extracting EXE.